# How to create a cronjob that runs every 5 minutes from 8:30 AM to 9:30 PM?

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run a cron job every 5 minutes from 8:30 AM to 9:30 PM. I've been searching around the web and here is what I came up with:

```
    30,35,40,45,50,55  8 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
    */5  9-21 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
    5,10,15,20,25,30 22 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
```

I have looked at cron job generators but they do not seem to address the requirement to start/end on the half-hour. Does anyone have a better or more concise solution?

Comment: Seems a reasonable solution. Typed more asking a question that in crontab - so what is the problem

Comment: This is untested, but since you can set cron on the 24 hour clock, I would assume you could set your time as `0830-1730`.  But as I said, I have NOT tested that

Comment: I'm not familiar with cron or Linux at all, so could you please elaborate as to how I could set the time? A code example would help. Thanks.

Comment: @jared: No, you can't do that. cron lets you specify, for example, a range of minutes within an hour. There's no syntax for `0830-1730`.

Comment: There are two votes to close this as off-topic. I disagree; there are plenty of questions here about writing crontabs, and it's arguably a (small) programming language. (It could also be a good question for http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
30-59/5  8    * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
*/5      9-20 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
0-30/5   21   * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
```

should also work, and easier to read.

Comment: That should work if you have an implementation that supports the `/` syntax. Not all do -- but Vixie cron, which is used by most Linux-based systems, does.

Comment: Agree, but the `/` syntax is already used in the example from ttemple.

Comment: This looks like a great answer. Just questioning if the third line above will make the job run until 10:30 PM instead of 9:30 PM? Should the "22" be "21" instead?

Comment: Yes, I took the example from your question but 22 should be 21 and 21 should be 20. In linux you can easily check the moments the cron job is executed by inspecting the syslog to know for sure (/var/log/messages).

Comment: Please edit your answer accordingly and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
30-59/5 8-20 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
00-25/5 9-21 * * * /path/to/whatever.sh >> /var/log/whatever.log 2>&1
```

would serve the purpose.